How to Handle “Field ‘courseid’ doesn’t have a default value” in MySQL with Manual CourseId Entry?
I am working on a .NET Core Web API project with MySQL as the database. In my database table courses, the courseid field is set as the primary key but does not have the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.
The issue arises when I try to insert a new course record, and the courseid is not explicitly provided or set to NULL. It throws the following error:

Exception has occurred: CLR/MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException An
exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in
System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code:  'Field
'courseid' doesn't have a default value'
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacketAsync(bool execAsync)

Currently, I have modified my code to require the user to explicitly input a CourseId, which works but is not ideal since the CourseId is no longer auto-arranged. Here’s the relevant part of my code: enter image description here
I tried modifying the table structure to set courseid as NULL or give it a default value directly through phpMyAdmin, but I do not have sufficient privileges to make these changes on the server. And I added a manual entry for CourseId, but this is less than ideal because it introduces a burden on the user and breaks the concept of sequential IDs.
Questions

How can I handle this error programmatically while still allowing courseid to be auto-arranged?
If I can’t modify the database structure (e.g., adding AUTO_INCREMENT), are there any workarounds in my C# code to emulate auto-increment functionality?
Is there a way to capture and retry inserting a record with a
dynamically generated unique ID if the user does not provide one?

Any suggestions or solutions to make this workflow smoother would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

I recommend to raise this issue to your manager and find the right person who has privileges to add the AUTO_INCREMENT option to the table's primary key. It will be more work, and risk race condition errors, if you try to code it yourself in your application.

Strictly speaking, you could use a combination of locking and selecting the max value from the course id column and increment it by one. But as Bill had already written, you would have to deal with a bunch of complications in case of concurrent access.

I'm not sure what "auto-arranged" means, but if it means your id's have to be in ascending order then you are left with 1) getting a lock on the table 2) getting the largest extant id 3) saving the new record with a larger one. 4) releasing the lock. This is objectively terrible, and you are much better off shouting loudly enough to get the db updated.
